# React useEffect Hook with a single dependency would run N+1 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

*useEffect* hook with a single dependency would invoke N+1 times, where N is the # of times the dependency mutated. There is an additional invocation that happens during the initial load. Is there a way we can avoid the initial invocation and ONLY run the hook when the dependency actually changed?
Here is an example, I am expecting the data to be 1, but if you run this, you would see the value will be 2.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [once, setOnce] = React.useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(0);
  let counter = 1;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setOnce(1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setData(data + 1);
  }, [once]);

  return <p>{data}</p>;
};
```

Here is a codepen

https://codepen.io/arbinish/pen/qBpXZdq

Comment: `if (once !== null) setData(data + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to the second useEffect to stop it from executing at the start such as

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if(once){
    setData(data + 1);
    }
  }, [once]);
```

Comment: That would work, but looks hacky. Doesn't React natively support this usecase?